# Python library to download and upload through SFTP and allow bandwidth throttling

Tags: library, windows-7, python, ubuntu, networking

I am looking for a Python that can download and upload through SFTP and allow  [bandwidth throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling) (e.g. max download speed: 10 MB/s).

[pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361424/395857) can download and upload through SFTP but has no bandwidth throttling option as far as I know.

It should work on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate or Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x64.

---

Ideally I'd like to write something along the line of

```
import pysftp #pip install sftp
import sys

hostname = "128.65.45.12"
username = "bob"       
password = "123456"  

sftp = pysftp.Connection(hostname, username=username, password=password)

sftp.get('/data/word_vectors/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt', max_speed=10)
print('done')
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794391/python-modules-for-scp-sftp-with-bandwidth-limitation

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) supports this according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72226751): You can provide a custom `callback` to [`SFTPClient.put`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) and [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) that `sleep`s for however long is needed to achieve the desired throttling effect.